# Make dialog windows windowed and not fullscreen by default

Tags: osx

I don't know what I changed but since a few days ago all context windows appear in fullscreen. But this causes problems, that all blender windows will get black. How can I change that new dialog boxes aren't displayed fullscreen?

This happens at least since 2.83

So how can I chose this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you add an image to show what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: @RayMairlot i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the system preferences > Interface > Editors > Temporary Windows , change  File Browser from Full screen to **New Window**.

[image]

Comment: All tough that didn't help directly, because I was in the new window mode, I changed it to fullscreen, which doesn't produce this glitch. Thank you very much!

Comment: A "glitch" might mean that there is an issue with the drivers for the GPU.

Comment: If the answer doesnt't solve the issue, then what is  the point of marking it as accepted?